Closed testing is in review after updating email list of tester
I have created an android app I upload I in Playstore after review I have to do closed testing but in closed testing as I updated the email list it states hat I have to sent for review and even after sending for review it takes long time.
My question is

Does it really required to review even after updating email list ?
Can I still test it with my all 20 testers while this review is reviewing so slow..??

I tried to remove sent for review and again send just for checking whether it was a bug or not !
Play console review Screenshot
Play console testing Screenshot


Yes it's is required to review you email list to validate that all the email are valid. And playstore need to enable the previlage to user of those email can access the close testing application on the Play Store using that email.

No you can't start testing while it's in review. Because that app will not be accessible by your 20 tester if the update is in review.


Let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks for replying but few of my users are able to download it while few are not thats why I'm confuse.

May I see a screenshot of your close testing case?

I updated my question, now you can see image over there

Well it's in good condition. Check the testing screen shot 2nd one there it's showing 20 tester required and 4 tester tested so far. That mean your all the tester in list can access the app on that link you shared or by searching in Play Store. If you haven't updated the tester list later .

Sorry for late reply,  but the problem is users email which I added after publishing are not able to download app from playstore as it shows Item not found.

Did you added the all 20 tester at the same time?

Nope, I added few after few hours

Okay it's seems to be . The email list you have added 2nd time those are not verified yet. Please wait some time once those re verified same user will be able to access those application

Also there is one more probability.  Assume you have added a email of a tester but that tester have more than one email added on the same phone/tab. Then that tester should select the testing Email in playstore in order to access the app

Well I tried  with my different mail id still the same problem so I think the problem is with verification part.
